# Best practices for JDBC accessor class

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am working on a small restaurant management app that will keep track of food orders. I am making a class that will handle all the SQL querying (for ease of use for my other teammates) and I want to know some of the best practices for doing so. The class will handle connecting/disconnecting/inserting and querying very specifically and will only take in basic parameters. I have the following design problems: Exception handling (should the user have to handle them, I prefer they do not), connecting (should the connection be re-established and closed on every query or just when a set of queries is done), and displaying results (how should I most elegantly convert a ResultSet, which can throw exceptions, do a stable finalized set of results).

TLDR;
What is the best design for a wrapper MySQL class that will make it so that the user of the class only needs to use built-in methods.

Comment: Thank you all for the excellent sources, but this is a good example to practice good style, and I was hoping that the design questions could be elaborated on.

Answer (score 2):

In 2013, we have enough frameworks that make database access simpler than plain JDBC.

Please have a look at [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/) for a bare-bones Active Record-like API or at [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) for something more complex. And if you want a taste of the future, have a look at [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/).

Comment: It's true that there are easier ways than re-inventing the wheel, but there is a possibility that his/her company doesn't allow third party software. So, I'm interested in an answer to the question.

Comment: These are excellent recources, but I wanted a little more low-level "roll-your-own" implementation. However, I may end up using these anyway.

Comment: @user3352280: Doing this yourself is going to be a huge waste of time. You'll spend many weeks just figuring out all the pitfalls that these frameworks already solve. That said, the jOOQ source code should be a great source of inspiration when you really do your own thing.

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirements, I would suggest that you use the Hibernate framework. It has all the features that you have mentioned built into it. Additionally it also helps in directly mapping the tables to simple POJOs.

Using Hibernate, you can set the properties that you want in an xml configuration file and then you can change it at will to get what you want. Exception handling is something the user should never have to do - Hibernate provides features for this. Since it maps the tables to POJOs, the ResultSet can be easily processed.

Comment: I would disagree with this.  Hibernate is not simple or lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to provide a roll your own answer.

Make methods throwable in your api, it is a common api practice.

A `ResultSet` is just like a `List<HashMap<String, dataType>>` :

> Create a List, and each record that is returned is populated into a
>   HashMap where the fieldName is the key and the data returned is the
>   value then add the HashMap to the List. For each record, create a new HashMap and repeat.

You can use metaData on a resultSet to get the number of Columns returned and the name of the columns returned.

```
    //rs is a ResultSet
    rs.getMetaData().getTableName(int Column);
    rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
```

Example Code for Select Query:

```
   private List<HashMap<String,Object>> selectQuery(sql) throws SqlException {
        //assumption that connection is a global
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> results = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        HashMap<String, Object> record = null;
        PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next() {
            record = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            for (int i : rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount()) {
                record.put(rs.getMetaData().getTableName(i), rs.getString(i));
            }
            results.add(record);
        }
        rs.close();
        return results;
    }
```

Connection
  -

> Keep the connection open until they close it. The developer should
>   know well enough that you should always close your connections else
>   create a leak.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take:

> The class will handle connecting

You should use a connection pool to acquire and manage connections.

> disconnecting

The connections should be acquired by services for each unit of work/use case.  The service is responsible for acquiring the connection from the pool closing the connection in a finally block, and committing or rolling back transactions.

> inserting and querying

easy to do.

> very specifically and will only take in basic parameters

has to take in whatever data is needed.  you don't know basic.

> I have the following design problems: Exception handling (should the
>   user have to handle them, I prefer they do not),

persistence exceptions should never bubble out of the service layer.  It should inform the user as to what happened, but not by sending exceptions.  user friendly messages are preferred.

> connecting (should the connection be re-established and closed on
>   every query or just when a set of queries is done),

connections should be open in the narrowest scope possible.  associate them with a unit of work/transaction.  the pool amortizes the cost.

> and displaying results (how should I most elegantly convert a
>   ResultSet, which can throw exceptions, do a stable finalized set of
>   results).

ResultSet should never, ever leave the persistence tier.  responsibility for closing it will be lost.  you should map all result sets into an object or collection of objects and return that.

Look at Spring JDBC template.  It's already sorted much of this out.

I would not recommend Hibernate.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I was not clear. This is not leaving the service level (by "users" I meant the other developers on my team). Do you think I should handle exceptions on my layer, or let them "bubble up" onto the next highest level.

Comment: "It depends".  Insufficient information to decide.  I would not recommend a blanket answer.  I'm not trying to design your system.